# Apache NIFI SSL cluster on separate VMs. Autorization issue(I guess)

Tags: apache-nifi

I need help in Apache NIFI cluster configuration. 
I configured standalone NIFI, cluster with no SSL, but during configuration NIFI cluster with SSL I faced some problems.

I guess the problem somethere between certificates generation and authorizers.xml file.

Error in ./logs/nifi-user.log:

```
2020-03-13 17:22:47,365 WARN [NiFi Web Server-22] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Rejecting access to web api: Untrusted proxy CN=myhost, OU=NIFI
```

Error in web UI:

```
Insufficient Permissions
Untrusted proxy CN=myhost, OU=NIFI
```

Here is my authorizers.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<authorizers>

<userGroupProvider>
<identifier>ldap-user-group-provider</identifier>
<class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.tenants.LdapUserGroupProvider</class>
<property name="Authentication Strategy">ANONYMOUS</property>

<property name="Manager DN"></property>
<property name="Manager Password"></property>

<property name="TLS - Keystore"></property>
<property name="TLS - Keystore Password"></property>
<property name="TLS - Keystore Type"></property>
<property name="TLS - Truststore"></property>
<property name="TLS - Truststore Password"></property>
<property name="TLS - Truststore Type"></property>
<property name="TLS - Client Auth"></property>
<property name="TLS - Protocol"></property>
<property name="TLS - Shutdown Gracefully"></property>

<property name="Referral Strategy">FOLLOW</property>
<property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
<property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>

<property name="Url">ldap://myldap.org:389</property>
<property name="Page Size"></property>
<property name="Sync Interval">30 mins</property>

<property name="User Search Base">ou=People,dc=mydomain,dc=org</property>
<property name="User Object Class">person</property>
<property name="User Search Scope">ONE_LEVEL</property>
<property name="User Search Filter"></property>
<property name="User Identity Attribute">uid</property>
<property name="User Group Name Attribute"></property>
<property name="User Group Name Attribute - Referenced Group Attribute"></property>

<property name="Group Search Base">ou=Group,dc=mydomain,dc=org</property>
<property name="Group Object Class">posixGroup</property>
<property name="Group Search Scope">ONE_LEVEL</property>
<property name="Group Search Filter"></property>
<property name="Group Name Attribute">cn</property>
<property name="Group Member Attribute">memberUid</property>
<property name="Group Member Attribute - Referenced User Attribute"></property>
</userGroupProvider>

<accessPolicyProvider>
<identifier>file-access-policy-provider</identifier>
<class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAccessPolicyProvider</class>
<property name="User Group Provider">ldap-user-group-provider</property>
<property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
<property name="Initial Admin Identity">iamadmin</property>
<property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>
<property name="Node Identity 1"></property>
<property name="Node Group"></property>
</accessPolicyProvider>


<authorizer>
<identifier>managed-authorizer</identifier>
<class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.StandardManagedAuthorizer</class>
<property name="Access Policy Provider">file-access-policy-provider</property>
</authorizer>
```

I created certificates using this command:

```
./bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone -n myhost1,myhost2,myhost3  --subjectAlternativeNames myhost1,myhost2,myhost3 -o ../standalonecerts/
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

P.S.: Don't anybody have an example of secured cluser confuguration in containers? Docker-compose file or something.

**UPD2:**

I did exactly as you said and now that part of config looks like this on all hosts:

```
   <accessPolicyProvider>
        <identifier>file-access-policy-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAccessPolicyProvider</class>
        <property name="User Group Provider">ldap-user-group-provider</property>
        <property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial Admin Identity">iamadmin</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>
        <property name="Node Identity 1">myhost1</property>
        <property name="Node Identity 2">myhost2</property>
        <property name="Node Identity 3">myhost3</property>
        <property name="Node Group"></property>
    </accessPolicyProvider>
```

But now nifi do not start at all.

Error myhost1:

```
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.authorization.exception.AuthorizerCreationException: org.apache.nifi.authorization.exception.AuthorizerCreationException: Unable to locate node CN=myhost1, OU=NIFI to seed policies.
```

Error myhost2:

```
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.authorization.exception.AuthorizerCreationException: org.apache.nifi.authorization.exception.AuthorizerCreationException: Unable to locate node CN=myhost2, OU=NIFI to seed policies.
```

**UPD3**

Ok, so I went to guide
[NIFI Admin Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#composite-file-and-ldap-based-users-groups)

, and here is my new autorizers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<authorizers>

    <userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>file-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="Users File">./conf/users.xml</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>

        <property name="Initial User Identity 1">CN=myhost1, OU=NIFI</property>

        <property name="Initial User Identity 2">CN=myhost2, OU=NIFI</property>


    </userGroupProvider>



    <userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>ldap-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.tenants.LdapUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="Authentication Strategy">ANONYMOUS</property>

        <property name="Manager DN"></property>
        <property name="Manager Password"></property>

        <property name="TLS - Keystore"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Keystore Password"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Keystore Type"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Truststore"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Truststore Password"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Truststore Type"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Client Auth"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Protocol"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Shutdown Gracefully"></property>

        <property name="Referral Strategy">FOLLOW</property>
        <property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
        <property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>

        <property name="Url">ldap://myldap:389</property>
        <property name="Page Size"></property>
        <property name="Sync Interval">30 mins</property>

        <property name="User Search Base">ou=People,dc=mydomain,dc=org</property>
        <property name="User Object Class">person</property>
        <property name="User Search Scope">ONE_LEVEL</property>
        <property name="User Search Filter"></property>
        <property name="User Identity Attribute">uid</property>
        <property name="User Group Name Attribute"></property>
        <property name="User Group Name Attribute - Referenced Group Attribute"></property>

        <property name="Group Search Base">ou=Group,dc=mydomain,dc=org</property>
        <property name="Group Object Class">posixGroup</property>
        <property name="Group Search Scope">ONE_LEVEL</property>
        <property name="Group Search Filter"></property>
        <property name="Group Name Attribute">cn</property>
        <property name="Group Member Attribute">memberUid</property>
        <property name="Group Member Attribute - Referenced User Attribute"></property>
    </userGroupProvider>


    <userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>composite-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.CompositeUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="Configurable User Group Provider">file-user-group-provider</property>
        <property name="User Group Provider 1">ldap-user-group-provider</property>
    </userGroupProvider>


    <accessPolicyProvider>
        <identifier>file-access-policy-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAccessPolicyProvider</class>
        <property name="User Group Provider">composite-user-group-provider</property>
        <property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial Admin Identity">iamadmin</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>
        <property name="Node Identity 1">CN=myhost1, OU=NIFI</property>
        <property name="Node Identity 2">CN=myhost2, OU=NIFI</property>
    </accessPolicyProvider>


    <authorizer>
        <identifier>managed-authorizer</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.StandardManagedAuthorizer</class>
        <property name="Access Policy Provider">file-access-policy-provider</property>
    </authorizer>

</authorizers>
```

But I still have error

```
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.authorization.exception.AuthorizerCreationException: org.apache.nifi.authorization.exception.AuthorizerCreationException: Unable to locate node CN=myhost2, OU=NIFI to seed policies.
```

Please, can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the node identities in authorizers.xml so that the correct proxy policy is created for each node:

```
<property name="Node Identity 1"></property>
```

Since you have already started the application once, you will need to stop the application, delete users.xml and authorizations.xml, then edit authorizers.xml to add the node identities, then start.

Comment: look at UPD2 . After changes NIFI do not start at all

Comment: The node identities need to match the DNs in the certs, so "CN=myhost1, OU=NIFI" and then those identities need to exist in the UserGroupProvider, so you either need to add them to your LDAP as if they were users, or you can use a CompositeUserGroupProvider which you can read about in NiFi Admin Guide

Comment: It looks correct, double check for whitespace and case sensitive issues, also make sure any time you change anything in authorizers.xml that you delete users.xml and authorizations.xml to start over

Comment: Yeah... I don't know what was the issue, I just tried to copy authorizers.xml example from official documentation and unexpectedly it worked. Thank you for your time!